# It appears integer variable i is not visible

Tags: java, android

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{
    b[i].setOnClickListener(
        new OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                justclicked(i);
            }
        }

    );
}
```

I am attempting to put an action listener on nine buttons using a for loop.  The code above is giving me an error.  Is the error caused by the value of i not being visible?  Thanks a lot, world-class experts @ Stack Overflow!!

Comment: 'i' would need to be final or static for that to work. Suggest you use the 'tag' or 'id' properties that all Views have to determine which view actually got clicked.

Comment: @ReubenScratton +1 for tag -1 for final :) (i know that you know that if he use final it will allways justclicked(8))

Comment: so ... as Reuben Scratton  wrote use tag ... `b[i].setTag(i);` before  `b[i].setOnClickListener ...` and then `justclicked((int)v.getTag());` or as Manfred Moser wrote build `class OCL implements OnClickListener{ public OCL(int i){this.i = i;}int i;            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                justclicked(i);
            }}` and use it like this `b[i].setOnClickListener(new OCL(i));`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it's because `i` isn't final, which it must be to access from an anonymous inner class.
Add

```
final int finalI = i;
```

before

```
b[i].setOnClickListener( ...
```

and then use `finalI` instead of `i`: `justclicked(finalI);`.

After that, think up a better name for `i` and `finalI`.

Comment: @Ryan Stewart and OP next question will be ... why in onClick i got always 8 :)

Comment: Doesnt final acts as static in c ?... and it will be pointing to the same var in every iteration .. So after all it will be 8?

Comment: No. You are initializing a new variable every iteration, so it will be the correct value each time.

Answer (score 2):

Create a class that implements OnClickListener with i as a constructor argument and use that to set the listeners.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the "tag" route you can use the following:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
            b[i].setTag(i);
            b[i].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    int value = Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString());
                    justclicked(value);

                }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 for(int i = 0; i<9;i++) {
    // use j for justclicked
    final int j = i;
    b[i].setOnClickListener(

        new OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {

                justclicked(j);

            }
        }


            );
```

Comment: hehe ... why `justclicked(j);` .... `justclicked(8);` do the same :) j will be always 8 in onClick :)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a view's property to access the index (if you must).
For instance you can utilize the *setTag()* method

```
v.setTag(index)
```

and

```
public void onClick(View v)
{
   int index = (int)v.getTag();
   justClicked(index);
}
```